# Internet Explorer 9 removing a favorite site

Tags: internet-explorer-9

To delete a favorite web site, I right click on the site but the link still remains after I press the delete key. What can I do?

Comment: I assume you mean you click on delete in the drop-down menu rather than push the delete key on your keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the directory `C:\Users\'[your user name]'\favorites`  and deleting the sites you do not want from there.

Answer (score 1):

Right clicking on a favorite should bring up a context menu.  When you hit the Delete key in the context menu, it won't do anything.
So either click on the Delete item on the pop-up menu or hit the associated hot key which is probably "D".